# Cohomological methods in intersection theory and derived categories

Tags: cohomology, derived-categories, derived-algebraic-geometry, enumerative-geometry

Are there any enumerative questions akin to: “What is the number of planes containing a given line tangent to a given cubic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$” that we can answer using derived categories? I've begun Eisenbud–Harris' *[3264 and All That](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139062046)* and am encouraged to know that there are some enumerative problems that are solved by constructing a line bundle and computing Chern classes of said line bundle, or maybe some intersection products in the Chow ring. But I still cannot see examples of enumerative problems or questions, if any, that derived categories can answer (or are useful for answering) which cannot be solved by either classical methods, or using the Chow ring.

I would be happy to know of any references on this topic.

Comment: I don't have an example, but I would guess that intersection homology has been applied to enumerative questions on singular spaces. Also, derived categories show up in calculations.